# search element(tuple) return index of list of list(matrix)

Tags: python, matrix, tuples

I have a matrix (list of list)the dimension is 701(row)*576(column) which the elements are tuple:

```
    matrix=[[(1.5,5.5),(1.5,5.6),(1.5,5.7),
              (1.7,5.8),(1.7,5.5),(1.7,5.6),
              .............................,
              .............................,
              (1.6,5.6),.......,(5.5,7.4)]]
```

I want to print the tuple that i want to search index/counter of my list of lists.

```
> (1.5,5.5) with index/counter 1 (1.5,5.6) with index/counter 2
> (1.5,5.7) with index/counter 3 (1.7,5.8) with index/counter 4
> (1.7,5.6) with index/counter 4 ......... .........
```

for example, I search the index/counter about myPoint :

```
myPoint=(5.5,7.4) that is the last point
myPoint => 403776(index/counter)
```

Comment: It might be better to show a **complete** example (of course much smaller than 701*576).

Comment: I hope now the example is clarer

Comment: @journpy No, it's the opposite I search for the tuple (1.5, 5.6) and I want to get 1

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. It prints the index of the tuple:

```
matrix=[[(1.5,5.5),(1.5,5.6),(1.5,5.7),(1.5,5.8)]]
my_point = (1.5,5.7)

for i,j in enumerate(matrix):
    for k,l in enumerate(j):
        if my_point == l:
            print(f"{my_point} => {k}")
```

The output will be `(1.5, 5.7) => 2`

Comment: thank you for the response, Iwrote more details about the question

Comment: This wouldn't print 403776 for their example.

Comment: According to your question, 403776 is the index of the last element in the list right?

Comment: You print the index in the inner list, not the overall one that they want.